# cas custom logout

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cas

while implementing jasig-CAS I've faced the next problem:
I want to implement the logout. For now it works fine, but I want CAS server to redirect the user after logging out to the server where the request came from(for instance, `http://localhost:8080/myApp`).
I've tried to add "service" in security context, but nothing happened
here is a piece of my spring security context:

```
<security:logout logout-url="/logout"
                        logout-success-url="https://localhost:9543/cas-server-webapp-3.4.10/logout?service=http://localhost:8080/myApp" 
                        invalidate-session="true" />
```

all configs and procedures are taken from [this manual.](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/cas.html)

Comment: Sorry for misleading you with redirect prefix, it was config of cas webflow. I deleted that answer.

Comment: About your issue: How exactly it is not working? Have you tried to put some simple url in `logout-success-url` parameter?

Comment: @AleksandrM now it logs out normally. BUT it logs out and goes to CAS logout page and I want to go(to be redirected) to myApp index page(or whatever) and not to stay at CAS logout page.

Comment: Can't you just use `http://localhost:8080/myApp` as `logout-success-url`?

Comment: nope, because in this case user is not actually logged out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this helps from default `cas-servlet.xml`

```
 <bean id="logoutController" class="org.jasig.cas.web.LogoutController"
    p:centralAuthenticationService-ref="centralAuthenticationService"
    p:logoutView="casLogoutView"
    p:warnCookieGenerator-ref="warnCookieGenerator"
    p:ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator-ref="ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator"
    p:servicesManager-ref="servicesManager"
    p:followServiceRedirects="${cas.logout.followServiceRedirects:false}"/>
```

Look at last line `${cas.logout.followServiceRedirects:false}`.

Comment: where I should add this prefix and what is the correct form of this prefix? or where can I look for it?

Comment: in this bean there was no such property, so I just added it and set it to true(so it enables redirecting). thanks for the answer and saved hours! ;)

Comment: p:followServiceRedirects="true" ,then ${cas_server_base_url}/logout?service=${app_base_url}

Answer (score -1):

**cas-servlet.xml**

```
  <bean id="logoutController" class="org.jasig.cas.web.LogoutController"
        p:centralAuthenticationService-ref="centralAuthenticationService"
        p:logoutView="casLogoutView"
        p:warnCookieGenerator-ref="warnCookieGenerator"
        p:ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator-ref="ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator"
        p:servicesManager-ref="servicesManager"
        p:followServiceRedirects="${cas.logout.followServiceRedirects:true}"/>
```

**In logout url**

```
<a href="/cas/logout?service=http://localhost:8080/myApp" title="Log Out">Logout</a>
```

Comment: some explanation should be added